# Telerik WinForm problems in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, telerik

I build wcf ,and it run's on Windows Server 2008 R2.Now i updated my program , and add Scheduler(telerik).

After this my aplication is start's to  crash.

Do any one know how to fix it?

Here my code that works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
       // public static SchedulerForm Scheduler = new SchedulerForm(); here Scheduler disabled
        private static NotifyIcon trayIcon;
        static void Main()
        {
           using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService.SimpleService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                SysTrayApp();
                Application.Run();
 }
        }

        public static void SysTrayApp()
        {
            /* tmNowActions = new ContextMenu();
            tmNowActions.MenuItems.Add("....
            my other function (not important)
            */

           // Scheduler.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
}
```

And here after i remove comments and enable scheduler

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static SchedulerForm Scheduler = new SchedulerForm();
        private static NotifyIcon trayIcon;
        static void Main()
        {
           using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService.SimpleService)))
            {
                host.Open();
                SysTrayApp();
                Application.Run();
 }
        }

        public static void SysTrayApp()
        {
            /* tmNowActions = new ContextMenu();
            tmNowActions.MenuItems.Add("....
            my other function (not important)
            */
           Scheduler.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
}
```

After this my aplication is crashed

Here the image from win server 2008 R2
[image]

[image]

Do any one know how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I found that i was missing some telerik dll's,after i add them i get a new error.

If  i will make empty WinForm all works fine,and i will see empty form ,but if i add telerik element(Scheduler in my case),i will get this error

[image]

Here another error that says i am missing Scheduler version,but you can see the dll and properties of this dll,and it is there it is not missing.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if that machine has .net installed on it.. also what version of .net did you compile the winforms in..? have you tried down grading it and then upgrading it in the properties window and I mean changing the version from .Net Version x.x.x to a lower version then saving it then changing it back to .net 4.0 or 4.5 then recompiling it.. also can you add better event logging error message to your code..?

Comment: Setup Adplus to take a Crash Dump and the use WinDBG to do a `!Analyze`. This should yield you some clues. Since the second chance exception is happening in the KernelBase.DLL you might need to log a support case with Microsoft to uncover the root cause. Or contact Telerik for Support otherwise upload a solution zip file here and let others see if they can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Hello.My version of .net is set to 4.0, i tried to lower to 3.5 and return to 4.0 not helped.On server i have .net 4.5.1 i added image of error

Comment: may I ask if you have debugged this on your local.. also make sure this is not a permissions issue.. does that server need a service account to run your scheduler..?

Comment: Yes i debugged this on my local pc,but i am working on win7,in vs2012 all work's and winApp.exe work's to.About (service account to run your scheduler) i will check,but i dont think this is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem like this:

1:Clean project and delete old files from Degub/bin.

2:Make sure all telerik dll's have the same version(end's .20 or .40)  **!!IMPORTANT!!**.

3:In Telerik dll's click properties, and then make Copy Local = true  **!!IMPORTANT!!**.

4:Rebuild the project.

After all this steps all start to work.